# How to save 10 last seconds from a custom camera app that constantly recording video on Android?

Tags: android, camera, buffer

I've already implemented "Camera app" from Android developers site.. 
My basic idea is constantly recording video (like a security camera) and when i click on a button it'll save the last 10 seconds on a separate file for later modifications.
is there a way to use buffers or something in Android Camera? 
thanks

Comment: I tried using the code from that post: https://nidesai.wordpress.com/2013/09/22/android-camera-capturing-raw-video-frames/ (with some changes to make it work for me) but it's far from ideal.. frame rate drops like a bass and there's no way to record sound as well.

Comment: I need the same thing exactly. Have you managed?

Comment: yes google "google grafika project" for buffer recording and "mp4parser" to mux it with audio that you will record asynchronously with the video (like new thread and save the date time that the user presses "Stop" ext.)

Comment: I don't need audio. Maybe you already have the code for saving X last seconds of video and can put it as an answer? Thanks.

Comment: Then you have exactly what you need here: https://github.com/google/grafika go to "grafika/src/com/android/grafika/" you will find what you need :)

Comment: "grafika/src/com/android/grafika/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java" **

Comment: Maybe you know what the lowest api version that's supported for recording the video is?

Comment: I believe its API 18

Comment: this issue solve or not using grafika?? @Barina

Comment: @Ali Sorry it is not.. I've forsaken this project long time ago.

Comment: @Barina Thanks for your reply. I already done it. 

Comment: The app "snipback" from "hipoint" seems to do this. I don't know how they do it.